# How to use template function for implicit conversion

Tags: c++, templates, implicit-conversion, template-argument-deduction

Very *simplified* example (nevermind what the class `A` and operators are doing, it's just for example):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <bool is_signed>
class A {
public:
    // implicit conversion from int
    A(int a) : a_{is_signed ? -a : a}
    {}

    int a_;
};

bool operator==(A<true> lhs, A<true> rhs) {
    return lhs.a_ == rhs.a_;
}

bool operator==(A<false> lhs, A<false> rhs) {
    return lhs.a_ == rhs.a_;
}

int main() {
    A<true> a1{123};
    A<false> a2{123};

    cout << (a1 == 123) << endl;
    cout << (a2 == 123) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This works.

But if I replace two `operator==`'s (with same body) with template:

```
template <bool is_signed>
bool operator==(A<is_signed> lhs, A<is_signed> rhs) {
    return lhs.a_ == rhs.a_;
}
```

, its compilation produces errors:

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:31:14: error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘A<true>’ and ‘int’)
  cout << (a1 == 123) << endl;
           ~~~^~~~~~
prog.cpp:23:6: note: candidate: ‘template<bool is_signed> bool operator==(A<is_signed>, A<is_signed>)’
 bool operator==(A<is_signed> lhs, A<is_signed> rhs) {
      ^~~~~~~~
prog.cpp:23:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
prog.cpp:31:17: note:   mismatched types ‘A<is_signed>’ and ‘int’
  cout << (a1 == 123) << endl;
                 ^~~
```

Is it possible to use template here? Can I use C++17 user-defined template deduction guides somehow? Or anything else?

Answer (score 6):

Implicit conversions are not considered in [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Implicit_conversions), which causes the deduction for `is_signed` fails on the 2nd function argument.

> Type deduction does not consider implicit conversions (other than type adjustments listed above): that's the job for [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution), which happens later.

If you always use the `operator==` in the style like `a1 == 123`, i.e. an `A<is_signed>` is always used as the 1st operand, you can exclude the 2nd function parameter from the deduction. e.g.

```
template <bool is_signed>
bool operator==(A<is_signed> lhs, std::type_identity_t<A<is_signed>> rhs) {
    return lhs.a_ == rhs.a_;
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/RtON15uIR7dbIAOI)

<sub>PS: [`std::type_identity`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity) is supported since C++20; even it's not hard to implement one.</sub>

Comment: One could also add the operator the other way around, but that takes extra effort to remove the ambiguity when comparing `A`s without implicit comparison (e.g. _another_ overload without any `std::type_identity_t`). https://godbolt.org/z/J39Veq

Answer (score 5):

Another alternative is `friend` function, so the function is not template, but use the template argument:

```
template <bool is_signed>
class A {
public:
    // implicit conversion from int
    A(int a) : a_{is_signed ? -a : a}
    {}

    int a_;

    friend bool operator==(const A& lhs, const A& rhs) {
        return lhs.a_ == rhs.a_;
    }
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bdf7b5b55378f1c6)

Answer (score 4):

Template argument deduction does not take implicit conversions into account. You need again two overloaded comparison operators.

```
template <bool is_signed>
bool operator==(A<is_signed> lhs, A<is_signed> rhs) {
    return lhs.a_ == rhs.a_;
}

template <bool is_signed>
bool operator==(A<is_signed> lhs, int rhs) {
    return lhs == A<is_signed>(rhs);
}
```